# Uploading Doc file using PHP

Tags: php, doc

I am facing problem regarding uploading doc file using php. I can successfully upload PDF file. But, once I am trying to upload doc file I am having error

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => OSP_Internal staffs login_04062012.docx ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )
```

As we can see, `tmp_name` is empty as rest of them expert. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: error 1 = "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini". the manual know's all, please read it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is set to one, which means the file is too big.

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

You can solve it by setting this in your .htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```